# Round method for <fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits>

Tags: java, jsp, tags, rounding

How does rounding works with this tag? Only docs I could find is this:

> Attributes are also provided to allow you to determine how many decimal places should be used. The minFractionalDigits and maxFractionalDigits attributes allow you to specify the number of decimal places. If the number exceeds the maximum number of fractional digits, **the number will be rounded**. --*How exactly??*

Is there something like default round method that I can change in this tag? Something like

```
RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN (*default*) --> RoundingMode.HALF_UP
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the implementation: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jstl-api - at first glance it uses default Java formatting without possibility to influence rounding.

Comment: So the only way to go would be to round the number before it reaches this tag, right? I suppose there is not any other effective way to do it... 
Thanks for any feedback